# cut -d not working?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, pipe, cut

I'm trying to extract all the lines from a file that end with /42 and then remove said /42 with the command cut but for some reason its not working. Here is the command

```
grep "42$" questionnaires.txt > test42 | cut -d '/' -f 1 test42
```

and the output when I use cat ont test42 is

```
La dernière armure... ?/42
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command

```
grep "42$" questionnaires.txt > test42 | cut -d '/' -f 1 test42
```

doesn't do anything like you think it does.

The first part:

```
grep "42$" questionnaires.txt > test42
```

That writes the output of `grep` to `test42`.  The *output* of that is nothing.

So that nothing then gets passed to

```
cut -d '/' -f 1 test42
```

Which is trying to read the file you're currently writing to, and sending the results to the screen.  That's likely to be no output, and the file `test42` will have the data without the `cut` being applied.

Now if you want the final file to just have the data you want to change the order:

```
grep "42$" questionnaires.txt | cut -d '/' -f 1 > test42
```

Now this means "get the results of the grep" and then "pass that through cut" and store the results of that in the file `test42`

Comment: thank you that was exactly what I needed and I will have to talk to my teacher.

Comment: This will be a problem with the `cut` command if you have other '/' characters in the line.  It's better to just remove the entire pattern since you know it.  (e.g. something like `sed -e 's|/42||g'`